# Adding text to a div shifts nearby divs downwards

Tags: html, css

My goal is to create a container, and inside there are 6 tilecards each with different content on them. When I try to implement text into one of the divs, the divs under them all shift downwards.

[Here's what it looks like when text is added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxgei.png)

I've looked for probably an hour and I haven't found a solution.
Here's my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="header">
   <p class="textheader"><b>websitetitle |</b></p>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
   <div class="navitem">
    <p class="navtext"><b>Home</b></p>
   </div>
   <div class="navitem">
    <p class="navtext">Info</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="boxinfowrapper">
   <div id="preboxtextdiv">
    <h1 id="preboxtext">title for box cards:</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="boxcontainer">
    <div class="tilecard">
    <p class="boxtext">Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tilecard">
    </div>
    <div class="tilecard">
    </div>
    <div class="tilecard">
    </div>
    <div class="tilecard">
    </div>
    <div class="tilecard">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```html
#header {
 background-color: #00ccff;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px;
 margin-top: -10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #50ADCC
}

body{
 margin: 0px;
}

.textheader {
 font-family: Verdana;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 margin-left: 10px;
 position: relative;
}

#navbar{
 width: 50%;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: white;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 text-align: center;
 margin: 3px auto;
}

.navitem {
 width: 80px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
}
.navitem:hover .navtext{
 color: #4dd2ff;
}
.navtext {
 color: black;
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: Courier;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.tilecard {
 margin-top: 30px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: lightgray;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
 transition: all 400ms ease;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px
}
.tilecard:hover {
 -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
 transition: all 400ms ease;
 background-color: gray;
}

#boxcontainer {
 position: relative;
 width: 720px;
 height: 495px;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0px auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 border-radius: 10px;
}
#preboxtextdiv {
 width: 600px;
 height: 30px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 30px auto;
 text-align: center;
}
#preboxtext {
 color: #80bfff;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}

#boxinfowrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #f0f5f5;
 margin: 100px auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.boxtext {
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Can you show a live code example on JSbin/JSFiddle or something like that? Images aren't very easy to work with

Comment: I hope this works: https://jsfiddle.net/txfnggbm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason lies in `display: inline-block;` for those containers - this will vertically align those elements along their baselines (= text base lines). To avoid that, add

```
.tilecard {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z0731w5x/

Comment: That works perfectly. That's so weird, I saw a bunch of other posts saying to do that, and each time I put the "vertical-align: top;" at the bottom after "margin-left: 10px;". When I put it where you did though, it works perfectly. Do you know why that is?

Comment: I can only guess, but the "margin-left: 10px" in your code above doesn't end with a semicolon, so if you add another rule in a line below it, this will be invalid code since the rules aren't seperated by the semicolon.

Comment: That would be the issue, thanks, I did not notice.

Answer (score 1):

The default `vertical-align` is `baseline`. Without text, the baseline of an inline-block element corresponds to the bottom of its *bounding rectangle*, not the text that it would normally contain.

Align your tilecards by their tops and all will be well.

```
.tilecard {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#boxcontainer {
position: relative;
width: 720px;
height: 495px;

->height: auto;

background-color: white;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Try this